# How to get python part.get_filename() , Encoding type?

Tags: python

I read an email file in python and i want to do something if file name is utf-8.

I use **part.get_filename()** function and it return something like this [('filename','asci')] it is tuple in a list object.

Is there any function to get Encoding type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning already the file type so You can handle it like this

```
file1 = part.get_filename()
fileEncode = file[1]
```

so the encoding type will be stored in fileEncode

Hopefully that helps